# Tensorflow fans with large dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, mean-square-error

I'm currently writing a neural network using tensorflow, and I'm finding that it all works as expected when I have a small dataset, but as soon as I increase the number of samples, I start getting nan's for my cost function. I'm using the mean_squared_error method as passing this into an AdamOptimiser. I'm also batching the data to be in manageable chunks.

I'm not in a place where I can paste code at the moment, so am not looking for an answer as to a specific error I'm making, but I'm wondering if large datasets can sometimes produce these results? It would seem a bit odd to me. What feels more likely is that there's a problem with my data, but being quite new to this, I don't have a feel for where to start looking. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
it was indeed my data, I had a few nans corrupting it all, but the dataset was so large it was tricky to find them. Anyway, should be all cleaned up now, I'll let you know if this solves my issue when working out the cost function.

**Update 2:**
This is now working after filtering out the rows with nans in them. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try to decrease the learning rate?

Comment: I did, but I don't have a good enough understanding of the internals to understand why that would help. I've seen that as a suggestion on a few posts, but it becomes nan in the first iteration. What about reducing the learning rate changes the loss function?

Comment: NaN is the output of infinity - infinity or 0/0. Can you do `check = tf.add_check_numerics_ops()` and do session.run on that? That may help you isolate where this computation happens. Some related issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2288 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2540

Comment: Is your batch size the same for either set?

Comment: The batch size is the same regardless of the size of the dataset, which is why I was leaning towards there being a problem in the data after a certain point.

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov, I'll try that tomorrow when I'm back with my code.